# Building Node from source with multi-stage docker leads to NPM module errors on cli.js

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, makefile, docker-multi-stage-build

I am building a custom docker image that requires I compile Node and a few other things from source. To create a small image I am using dockers multi-stage builds and copying artifacts over to a final stage with minimal dependencies.

With a few challenges, I currently have node copied into my target final image and executing node and basic tests are working correctly, however npm is throwing the following error;

```
Error: Cannot find module '../lib/cli.js'
Require stack:
- /usr/local/bin/npm
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:946:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:787:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1012:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/bin/npm:2:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1112:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1166:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:834:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/usr/local/bin/npm' ]
}
```

However, executing this in the "build" stage npm runs correctly without errors. It seems *something* is missing, but i cannot figure it out.

Inspecting the build image, I have found the symlink refers to `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js` If I run this file directly, it runs successfully, modifying the links from /usr/local/bin/npm to this does not correct the problem. For example;

```
root@4a93b17b5087:/# /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js -v
8.12.1
```

I can confirm the files are all present. Trialing a few things, here are the layers I copy over. It seems node spits out a lot of stuff in many locations. These are the default locations when running `./configure && make && make install`

```
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/bin/* /usr/local/bin/
COPY --from=builder /node/out /node/out
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib
```

Using strace `strace npm -v` since my paths/local bin is working produces some interesting errors.

```
statx(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/bin", AT_STATX_SYNC_AS_STAT, STATX_ALL, {stx_mask=STATX_ALL|0x1000, stx_attributes=0, stx_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, stx_size=66, ...}) = 0
statx(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/lib/cli.js", AT_STATX_SYNC_AS_STAT, STATX_ALL, 0x7ffc3e47c2b0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
statx(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/lib/cli.js.js", AT_STATX_SYNC_AS_STAT, STATX_ALL, 0x7ffc3e47c1d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
statx(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/lib/cli.js.json", AT_STATX_SYNC_AS_STAT, STATX_ALL, 0x7ffc3e47c1d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
statx(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/local/lib/cli.js.node", AT_STATX_SYNC_AS_STAT, STATX_ALL, 0x7ffc3e47c1d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Is there something as part of the install I am missing, or am I running into some kind of bug?

Answer (score 0):

So I ended spotting some weirdness between my build and final images. By injecting the cli.js into the path strace said was not existing, the error changes to something about semver.js.

By locating all instances of semver.js I noticed some odd quirks to the dirs, in the end I have ended up with:

```
COPY --from=builder /usr/local /usr/local
```